# How "lie" in present simple becomes "lying" in present continuous?

Tags: present-continuous

How "**lie**" in present simple becomes "**lying**" in present continuous?

Where the letter **y** in the word 'lying' did come from, while in the infinitive form it's 'lie'?

My friend came across this text-book which practices 'present continuous tense' and I really don't know how to explain it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

All verbs in current 'standard' English that end in '-ie' have their present continuous ending in '-ying.

lie ----> lying

die ----> dying

tie ----> tying

vie ----> vying

Don't expect English spelling to make sense - it doesn't. To an English native 'Lieing' etc. just doesn't look right.

Comment: Yes, but why does ***ie*** becomes ***y*** in a verb + ing form?

Comment: @user070221 The answer given explains that very thing.

Comment: @JasonBassford - it explains the spelling rule, not its origin.

Comment: @user070221 As the last sentence states, "don't expect English spelling to make sense—it doesn't." (The conjugation of *to be* is another example. *Was* and *am* look nothing like *be*, yet that's what we use . . .)

Comment: @JasonBassford - this is just a dismissive answer. The fact that you don’t know the origin of a spelling, doesn’t mean that there is no  origin. This might be a starting point - https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ie#etymonline_v_34648

Comment: @user070221 There may be an *origin* (then again that may have been lost in time too) but that doesn't mean there is an *explanation*. We have no idea why some words are spelled or pronounced the way they are or the name of the person who first introduced them. It's simply that they are out there in the wild and have become commonly used. (And English is a nightmarish creation, given its history of patchwork composition and change.) Questions about etymology specifically are better asked at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JasonBassford - I agree that this is question should be migrated to ELU.